# How to review content before publish in Umbraco CMS? (Description Inside)

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco-blog

I'm using umbraco CMS and creating a site like blog. Including me there are 10 members involved in 
writing article's but i'm the one who needs to check the article.

All 10 members are not in a single place. The thing I want to know is if a person other than me is putting a content, I only want to decide whether to publish or not. Is there a option to set this kind of permission.

would somebody say can we done this in umbraco CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

Within the Users section, there's a node called `User Types` and from your description it sounds like `Writer` is best suited for your members. Just make sure they are set as this user type when creating/updating their respective user nodes. Most notably, they'll have the following permissions amongst others:

- Create
- Update
- Send to Publish

There's a bunch of other permissions there that you can choose from if `Writer` doesn't precisely match your requirements or you could create your own user type from scratch.